# Permission Requirement to migrate MongoDB to ApsaraDB for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I want to migrate my existing MongoDB 3.6 to ApsaraDB for MongoDB. What type of permission required for Migration. 
Is there any steps defined for MongoDB migration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DTS allows you to migrate data from on-premises MongoDB to ApsaraDB for MongoDB. With the data change replication function, you can perform the migration without stopping services.

**Migration types**

For data migrations from on-premises MongoDB to ApsaraDB for MongoDB, DTS supports the following migration types: migrate existing data and replicate data changes. The features and restrictions of these migration types are as follows:

- Migrate existing data

  This migrates all existing data in the source instance to the target instance.
- Replicate data changes

If you also choose to replicate data changes, the data changes made to the source instance during the migration will be synchronized to the target instance, so that eventually the source instance is dynamically synchronous with the target instance. This allows you to perform the migration while on-premises MongoDB remains operational.

**Migration functions**

- The supported MongoDB versions are 3.0 and 3.2.
- MongoDB existing data migration supports:

  - Database migration
  - Collection migration
  - Index migration
- MongoDB data change replication supports:

  - Synchronization of create, delete, update operations on documents
  - Synchronization of create and delete operations on collections
  - Synchronization of create and delete operations on databases
  - Synchronization of create and delete operations on indexes

**Migration procedure**

The following describes the procedure of configuring a migration task from on-premises MongoDB to ApsaraDB for MongoDB.

**Create accounts**
When configuring a migration task, you need to provide the accounts of the source and target instances. The accounts must have the permissions listed in the preceding Migration permissions section.

If the source or target MongoDB instance does not have an account with required permissions, create one as follows:

```
db.createUser({user:"username",pwd:"password",roles:[{role:"rolename1",db:"database_name1"},{role:"rolename2",db:"database_name2"}]})
```

**Parameter description:**

- username: Username of the account to be created
- password: Password of the account to be created
- rolename1/rolename2: Roles to be assigned to the username. Example roles are read and readWrite.
- database_name1/database_name2: In the preceding example, role1 and role2 of database_name1 and database_name2 are assigned to the username.

You can check [this link](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/26625.htm) for more detailed information